# Creating custom scaling trigger for elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, cloudamqp

I have a worker that uses RabbitMq as the message queue

I want to configure the worker to scale depending on the number of messages in the queue

Am using cloudamqp how do I add a custom scaling trigger in elastic beanstalk

Answer (score 0):

You can poll the RabbitMQ HTTP API: https://raw.githack.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/rabbitmq_v3_5_6/priv/www/api/index.html

eg. curl https://user:pass@srv1.rmq.cloudamqp.com/api/queues/myvhost?columns=name,messages

Comment: And how do you add a custom trigger in elastic beanstalk